# Set screen orientation for the whole app

Tags: java, android, android-activity, screen-orientation

I am implementing a way where the user can disable screen rotation from the app settings. If the box is checked then any `Activity` can be automatically rotated and follow the phone rotation settings. If not checked then the autorotation is disabled.

I know how to do it per `Activity` like this

```
if(!GlobalVar.sharedPreferences_static.isAutoRotate()){
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}else{
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER);
}
```

Is there a way I can do this once for all the activities (the whole app) instead of doing it for every `Activity`? Thank you.

Comment: I think, No way to do in via one actvity. You need to added code in every activity.

Comment: But you cannot set the orientation for whole application you can set the single activity...only if you want to set the orientation for a particular activity you set like below my answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, here is what you can do: create an empty `Activity` (without setting its content) like this:

```
public class EmptyActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Your screen orientation logic here
    }
}
```

and then you make all other `Activities` extend the `EmptyActivity`. So, you just need to implement your screen orientation logic once.

Comment: This is good solution. The only problem though is that I have async task that excutes to load the activity as soon as the activity starts. Putting the code above is causing a screen orientation during the asyc task!

Answer (score 1):

The same thing can be done in the manifest with:

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

but that attribute doesn't work if (only) applied to the application tag. You'd still have to put it on every activity, but at least it's syntactically easier.

Comment: AFAIK  `screenOrientation` not supported for application tag.

Comment: Correct. I just tested putting it on the application tag. It didn't complain, but also didn't actually work.

Answer (score 0):

You just add this line into your activity like this

```
            <activity
                android:name="Package name"
                android:label="App anem"
                android:screenOrientation="landscape" //Orientation 
               >
            </activity>
```

Or you can set like this programmatically  like this in the starting of the activity...

```
if (Config.sDeviceType.equalsIgnoreCase("MO")) {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        }
```